# Generate delyed soundtrck - matlab

Tags: matlab, wav

I am trying to write a function that take as input an .avi file and returned the same video but with a delayed sound track. I am using `ffmpeg` and I encountered a problem. this is the function:

```
function Delyed = Dely_Movie_Soundtrack(filename,delayed)  
 Wav_File_Name = strrep(filename, '.avi', '.wav'); %the output file  
 wav = ['ffmpeg -i',' ',filename,' ','-vn -acodec copy',' ',Wav_File_Name]; %the command  
 system(wav); %executes the commant  
 [signal, Fs] = wavread('Will.wav');  
 size(signal)  
end
```

I get the following error

```
Data compression format (Format #85) is not supported.
```

I read about it on the net, but I didn't find useful (working) links.
any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the `ffmpeg` command complaining or the Matlab `wavread` command?  Try wrapping both in a try-catch, `try; system(wav); catch ME; disp(ME.message); disp('system died'); end;` Try a similar thing for the `wavread`.

Comment: the error regards to the wavread('Will.wav').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specificaly instruct the program to encode in a "raw" state, otherwise it just gives the name .wav, but in fact it remains mp3. This is the command:

```
  wav = ['ffmpeg -i',' ',filename,' ','-vn -coder:a raw',' ',Wav_File_Name];
```

thanks